# HTML Flask Page not reloading using fetch()

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing an app to upload object files to buckets. The app has the ability to browse for a file and submit it with a button, which successfully uploads the file. The problem is, I have to reload the page to see the new file on the screen and clear the "browsed" file selection. I typically use the following post function, but it is not working with the file selection. To which I found the fetch() method helpful, but found the problem stated above.

Helping with either problem would be great. My post() function is not working with files for some reason, I cannot do a request.files['thisFile'] after submitting to "/uploadToBucket". And the fetch post works, but I need to refresh the page manually or with "window.location = window.location.href;" which causes other issues.

```
function upload(bucket) {
  const selectedFile = document.getElementById('bucketUpload').files[0];
  let formData = new FormData();
     
  formData.append("thisFile", selectedFile);
  formData.append("bucket", bucket);

  fetch('/uploadToBucket', {method: "POST", body: formData});
  
  // fetch('/uploadToBucket', {
  //   method: "POST",
  //   body: formData
  // }).then(() => {
  //   window.location = window.location.href;
  // })

  // parameters = {
  //   bucket: bucket,
  //   thisFile: selectedFile,
  // }
  // post("/uploadToBucket", parameters);
}
```

and here is my post()

```
function post(path, params, method='post') {
    // The rest of this code assumes you are not using a library.
    // It can be made less verbose if you use one.
    const form = document.createElement('form');
    form.method = method;
    form.action = path;

    for (const key in params) {
    if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        const hiddenField = document.createElement('input');
        hiddenField.type = 'hidden';
        hiddenField.name = key;
        hiddenField.value = params[key];

        form.appendChild(hiddenField);
    }
    }
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure `fetch` is desired _because_ it doesn't refresh the page. You may need to use a form?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I tried that before the fetch, you can see the commented out parameters and post("/uploadToBucket", parameters). When I tried that method, doing content = request.files.get('thisFile', None) always returned None.

Answer (score 0):

`fetch` provides an API to obtain a response from the backend when a certain task is complete. In your example:

```
// Front end
fetch('/uploadToBucket', {method: "POST", body: formData})
   .then((response) => { 
      // update the page to view the file and clear form fields //
      let myForm = document.getElementById('my-form');
      myForm.reset();
});

// Back end
def view(request):
    # upload document with the mechanism you have in place #
    all_files = ... # query all your files after the upload #
    return HttpResponse(all_files)
```

Does this give you a direction to proceed?